# mvnpdf vs regular normal(gaussian) PDF - matlab / C

Tags: c, matlab, probability

I'm performing gaussian mixture model classification, and based on that, used "mvnpdf" function in MATLAB.

As far as I know the function returns a multi variate probability density for the data points or elements passed to it.

However I'm trying to recreate it on C and I assumed that mvnpdf is the regular Gaussian distribution (clearly it is not) because the results don't match.

Does anyone know how "mvnpdf" works ? Because I haven't been able to find documentation on it .

Comment: Hi Raaj, it is unclear what exactly is the problem. Do you want to know how `mvnpdf` works? Well you can look at the code, and this isn't a good SO question anyway. Is the problem that you couldn't recreate it in C? So how did you recreate it, show us the code. How do you know that your implementation is correct? What do mean by "it clearly is not regular Gaussian distribution"? It gives the pdf of the multivariate normal distribution – what about that is "not regular"? And how does the Octave documentation your own answer links to actually provide an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for mvnpdf is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html)

if you are looking for the exact code just put a break point at the point where you call it and see how it works

Comment: No actually it doesn't help much. The theory behind the code or algorithm is what I'm looking for to understand what's going on inside it .

Answer (score 0):

Okay I actually found a decent link that explains in detail what's happening inside .

This might be a better link to look at - http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/mvnpdf.html